# Add a Macerating toilet to washing machine drain line

Tags: plumbing

I have small area to work with and was wondering if I could add a macerating toilet on top of this extended platform which will house a washing machine. This is an older image, the top is actually done now and can support the weight on top of it. The washing machine drain is 2". I've been looking at the specification for some macerating toilets, and it seems like it's possible to join the drain to the 2" outlet. It's hard for me to find out if there are any other limitation as the topic is outside my wheelhouse. Any advice would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I had to goole it to confirm my suspicion. Macerating toilet is basically a blender for your poop making it small enough to use a 1.5 or 2 inch pipe. Make sure you have a good P-trap and roof vent

Comment: I’m not up on the latest code, but in my area when I installed my clothes washing machine, it mandated a dedicated 2” line with an unimpeded 18” drop to handle the rapid influx of water when the clothes washer does its drain cycle. Even if there isn’t code prohibiting it, if someone happens to flush at the exact moment the washer is also dumping, that could become one big unsanitary back flowing mess in a jiffy.

Answer (score 0):

2" outflow is fine for the mascerator.  Generally they'll pump 10' vertically.  You should have the proper height standpipe for the washing machine though and it looks like your plumbing goes down so I am not sure why you don't want to do a standard toilet?  I imagine your 2" line is joining up with a 3" below this level?

I went with a sewage ejector package when my sewer line was higher than my lowest bathroom group.

The nice thing is then you just plumb everything to normal code and don't have to buy anything special or be stuck with a particular style of toilet.  The basin takes a cast iron sewer pump which can be replaced.  Then you just have a standard toilet and everything is plumbed as if there was no ejector.

Mine is an above ground unit so it just sits on the floor of my crawl space.  You can get an in ground one which is quite a bit cheaper but then you have to dig a pit.

[image: Liberty Sewer Ejector]

Comment: Yes the washer drain joins a 3" drain under the floor. The sewer line is not above the bathroom group. The reason I'm not adding a standard toilet is due to avoiding breaking the foundation and space limitation (I would rather have the toilet on top of the washing machine for a more compact bathroom, this is a very small room and every inch counts)